# Meteor/Fibers - How to use Meteor.call callback?

Tags: serialization, meteor, fiber

I have this code, where I call a Meteor method from the client and expect a result in the callback. the `results` object is a well formed object that I can stringify and print from the server's console.

When I run this code, with a valid results and no error, the callback is not called on the client. However, if I substitute `fut.return(results)` with `fut.return(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)))`, the callback is called and I get "a string" in the client. Any idea why I can return a string but no object?

Server code (in `Meteor.Methods()`):

```js
getUserEvents : function(userId,start,end) {
        var fut = new Future();
        getUserEventsPrivate(userId,start,end,function(err,results){
            if(err){
                fut.throw(new Meteor.Error( 500, 'Oops, something wrong happened'));
            }else{
                fut.return(results); // works when fut.return(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(results)));
            }
        });
        return fut.wait();
    }
```

Client:

```js
Meteor.call('getUserEvents',Meteor.user()._id, startStr, endStr,function(err,results){
    console.log(results);
});
```

**EDIT**
here is the Json I'm trying to pass as 'results':

```
[
  {
    "title": "ResponsiveMTL #1",
    "start": "2015-10-13T21:30:00.000Z",
    "end": "2015-10-14T00:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Meteor Global Distributed Hackathon",
    "start": "2015-10-10T15:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2015-10-11T15:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "retenues a la source",
    "start": "2015-10-08T19:25:00.275Z",
    "end": "2015-10-08T19:25:00.275Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Salsa",
    "start": "2015-09-19T22:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2015-09-19T23:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "Salsa",
    "start": "2015-10-09T22:00:00.000Z",
    "end": "2015-10-09T23:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: try changing `return fut.wait()` to `fut.wait(); return fut.value;`

Comment: Of course `result` instead of `results` is just a typo, right?

Comment: @apendua Of course :)

Comment: Can you also compare the `results` object on the server before and after `parse/stringify` trick?

Comment: What do you mean by compare?

Comment: Can you add an example of `results` or shed some light on what it looks like? Any error or indication in the server console?

Comment: I added the JSON I am trying to pass as a result to the question

Comment: I am able to return this object from my method. If you return this **exact** object literally, does it still fail?

Comment: @MasterAM That is exactly my question: I pass the object by pasting its litteral value, it works. I stringify and parse 'results' and then pass it, it works. But if I pass 'results' nothing happens, not even an error is thrown. The call back is just not called on the client

Comment: I would begin by trying to clone it using `EJSON.clone()` and see if any exceptions are thrown. Again, without the actual object I cannot reproduce.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91871/discussion-between-masteram-and-nathanz).

Answer (score 1):

It is entirely possible to return an object this way.

Your object is probably not EJSON-serializable out of the box, although it is hard to tell without actually looking at a sample of it.

If, for example, your objects contain circular references, EJSON will silently fail and your callback won't be called. It is unlikely that this is the case, as you are able to get JSON to serialize it.

You can try to find the offending properties and modify them, but it might be a good idea to register it as a custom type with EJSON.

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson_add_type

Anyway, it would be interesting to see your actual objects and be able to tell more.
What version of Meteor are you using?

Comment: I added the JSON I am trying to pass as a result to the question

Comment: @NathanZ, see my comments in chat. Hope that we can sort this one out. Interesting test case.